# CSS "selective" clearing of floats

Tags: css, css-float

I have a bunch of blocks I'm floating left. They're of varying heights; some short, some tall.

Now, these blocks are dynamically generated, so there's no predicting how tall each block will be (or how many there'll be). Needs to be flexible, though, so if those blocks don't all fit one one row, well, I need a second row.

Problem: since the blocks are of varying height, any block that spills over onto the next row gets "nestled" among the existing floats: [image]

I need the spillover-blocks to form their own row: [image]

I know this is proper behavior (floats favor higher positions over left-er positions), but what's the best solution for this? I can change the HTML structure (and obviously any CSS), but I can't hardcode in a `clear: left`.

[Here's a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/EQyVy/13/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` on the blocks; save `float` for situations where you actually need to wrap text around an element.

Results: http://jsfiddle.net/EQyVy/18/

Comment: Absolutely genius. Thanks! (I knew it was something stupidly simple like that.)

Comment: +1 for the explanation on using `display: inline-block` over `float`.